# Matching at least 1 of 3 Scala Regexes using an Applicative Functor

Tags: regex, scala, scalaz, applicative

I have three Scala regular expressions that I need to test to see if any of them matches a given String.

I know that I can do the following:

```
val matches = R1.findFirstIn(myString).isDefined ||
              R2.findFirstIn(myString).isDefined ||
              R3.findFirstIn(myString).isDefined
```

but I believe that there is a way to do this using an Applicative Functor or Monad from the [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) library.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the sum under the "first" (or "last") monoid instance for `Option`. In Scalaz 7 you can write:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val R1 = "[a-c]".r
val R2 = "[d-f]".r
val R3 = "[g-i]".r

val m: Option[String] = List(R1, R2, R3).map(_.findFirstIn("test").first).suml
```

Or, alternatively:

```
val r1m = R1.findFirstIn("test").first
val r2m = R2.findFirstIn("test").first
val r3m = R3.findFirstIn("test").first

val m: Option[String] = r1m |+| r2m |+| r3m
```

Note that both of these solutions return the match itself, which you can of course call `isDefined` on if you want the same behavior as in your implementation.

---

As a side note, the `|+|` for the first monoid instance here is just `orElse` in the standard library, so you can write this almost as succinctly without Scalaz:

```
List(R1, R2, R3).map(_.findFirstIn("test")).reduce(_ orElse _)
```

Which is of course not an argument against using Scalaz, since it lets us capture the abstraction more cleanly, and provides an elegant way to change the behavior with regard to whether the first or last `Some` is returned.

Comment: Thanks. I have been reading a lot on Functors, Applicative Functors, Monoids, and Monads, both in Haskell and Scala, but get my head wrapped around it is still difficult.

Comment: Should the `first` calls be changed to `head`? `first` is annotated as deprecated.

Comment: I'd prefer `Seq(R1,R2,R3).exists(_.findFirstIn("test").isDefined)` since it it'll stop when it finds the first match, so is more efficient.

Comment: @Ralph: The `.first` here is a Scalaz 7 pimped method that changes the `Option` into a `FirstOption`. In Scalaz 6 you'd use `.fst` instead (and would also need to change `.suml` to `.asMA.sum`).

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: Right, but the question wasn't really asking for standard library alternatives—I only mentioned `orElse` because of the equivalence to the first monoid's `|+|`.